# Erlang Tuple match element types

Tags: erlang, tuples

So I'm trying to write tic-tac-toe for erlang using touples (a learning exercise). I always want a Board variable to be a tuple of nine elements. I've got the win matching down, but the matching to a cat's game is proving difficult. I want to do `{_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_}` -> "Cat's Game!"; , but that would match other elements like `[]`, or `""`, when I only want it to match x OR y, but nothing else. Example:

```
{(x||y),(x||y),(x||y),(x||y),(x||y),(x||y),(x||y),(x||y),(x||y)} -> "Cat's game!"
```

is essentially what I want to do, but I don't know how to do this with Erlang tuples, and it's proving difficult to google.

```
-module(d2bonus).
-export([status/1]).

status(Board) ->
    case Board of
{x,x,x,_,_,_,_,_,_} -> "X Wins!";
{o,o,o,_,_,_,_,_,_} -> "O Wins!";
{_,_,_,x,x,x,_,_,_} -> "X Wins!";
{_,_,_,o,o,o,_,_,_} -> "O Wins!";
{_,_,_,_,_,_,x,x,x} -> "X Wins!";
{_,_,_,_,_,_,o,o,o} -> "O Wins!";
{x,_,_,x,_,_,x,_,_} -> "X Wins!";
{o,_,_,o,_,_,o,_,_} -> "O Wins!";
{_,x,_,_,x,_,_,x,_} -> "X Wins!";
{_,o,_,_,o,_,_,o,_} -> "O Wins!";
{_,_,x,_,_,x,_,_,x} -> "X Wins!";
{_,_,o,_,_,o,_,_,o} -> "O Wins!";
{x,_,_,_,x,_,_,_,x} -> "X Wins!";
{o,_,_,_,o,_,_,_,o} -> "O Wins!";
{_,_,x,_,x,_,x,_,_} -> "X Wins!";
{_,_,o,_,o,_,o,_,_} -> "O Wins!";
({P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8,P9}) when (P1 =:= x orelse P1 =:= y), (P2 =:= x orelse P2 =:= y), (P3 =:= x orelse P3 =:= y), (P4 =:= x orelse P4 =:= y), (P5 =:= x orelse P5 =:= y), (P6 =:= x orelse P6 =:= y), (P7 =:= x orelse P7 =:= y), (P8 =:= x orelse P8 =:= y), (P9 =:= x orelse P9 =:= y) -> "Cat's Game!";
_ -> "No winner yet"
end
.
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be strict, you can do:

```
f({P1,P2,...}) when (X1 =:= x orelse X1 =:= y), (P2 =:= x orelse P2 =:= y), ... ->
  "Cat's game!".
```

I would do something like:

```
f(Board) when is_tuple(Board), size(Board) =:= 9 ->
   true = lists:all(fun(x) -> true; 
                       (y) -> true; 
                       (_) -> false 
                    end, 
                    tuple_to_list(Board)),
   "Cat's Game".
```

But that's mostly because I have a low tolerance for long winded checks.

Comment: Is the f in f({P1,P2,...}) critical? I don't understand what that is/does. Thanks for taking the time to try to help me! I also editted the top post to reflect what I'm talking about.

Comment: the f was the method (might be using the wrong term). removing the f and quotes, putting it into my case statement, flushing out the ... parts, and changing y to o made this work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could validate your input values before they get into your tuple, like:

```
make_move(Pos, Z, StateTuple) when Pos >= 1, Pos =< 9, (Z =:= x orelse Z =:= y)  ->
  erlang:setelement(Pos, StateTuple, Z).
```

Comment: Thanks for this. In typical learning fashion I'm doing something that doesn't make total sense and passing this the entire board in one shot rather than moves. Thanks for trying to help though!

Answer (score 1):

Couple more

```
is_cats_game1(Board) when is_tuple(Board), size(Board) =:= 9 ->
  [] =:= [Z || Z <- tuple_to_list(Board), Z =/= x andalso Z =/= y].

-define(is_yx(E), (E =:= x orelse E =:= y)).
is_cats_game2({Z1,Z2,Z3,Z4,Z5,Z6,Z7,Z8,Z9} = __Board)
   when ?is_yx(Z1)
        andalso ?is_yx(Z2)
        andalso ?is_yx(Z3)
        andalso ?is_yx(Z4)
        andalso ?is_yx(Z5)
        andalso ?is_yx(Z6)
        andalso ?is_yx(Z7)
        andalso ?is_yx(Z8)
        andalso ?is_yx(Z9) ->
  true;
is_cats_game2(_) -> false.
```

Answer (score 0):

-module(d2bonus).
-export([status/1]).

status(Board)->
    case Board of
        {x,x,x,*,*,_,*,*,_} -> "X Wins!";
        {o,o,o,*,*,_,*,*,_} -> "O Wins!";
        {*,*,_,x,x,x,*,*,_} -> "X Wins!";
        {*,*,_,o,o,o,*,*,_} -> "O Wins!";
        {*,*,_,*,*,_,x,x,x} -> "X Wins!";
        {*,*,_,*,*,_,o,o,o} -> "O Wins!";
        {x,*,*,x,*,*,x,*,*} -> "X Wins!";
        {o,*,*,o,*,*,o,*,*} -> "O Wins!";
        {*,x,*,_,x,*,*,x,*} -> "X Wins!";
        {*,o,*,*,o,*,*,o,*} -> "O Wins!";
        {*,_,x,*,*,x,*,*,x} -> "X Wins!";
        {*,*,o,*,*,o,*,*,o} -> "O Wins!";
        {x,*,*,_,x,*,*,_,x} -> "X Wins!";
        {o,*,*,_,o,*,*,_,o} -> "O Wins!";
        {*,*,x,*,x,*,x,*,*} -> "X Wins!";
        {*,*,o,*,o,*,o,*,*} -> "O Wins!";
        {P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8,P9} when (P1 =:= x orelse P1 =:= o), (P2 =:= x orelse P2 =:= o), (P3 =:= x orelse P3 =:= o), (P4 =:= x orelse P4 =:= o), (P5 =:= x orelse P5 =:= o), (P6 =:= x orelse P6 =:= o), (P7 =:= x orelse P7 =:= o), (P8 =:= x orelse P8 =:= o), (P9 =:= x orelse P9 =:= o) -> "Cat's game!";
        _ -> "No winner yet"
    end
.